# How to unbold other links when other links are active?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make the clicked link bold, but it should remove the bold from that link when I click on other links. I've tried the code below, which does make the link bold when I click on one, but the previously clicked links stay bold after I've clicked on other links.

How can I remove the bold from the previously clicked links when a new link is clicked?

```
<a href="#">link A</a>
<a href="#">link B</a>
<a href="#">link C</a>
<a href="#">link D</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $(this).css("font-weight","bold");
    });
});
```

Comment: In Event handler `$(this).addClass('bold').siblings('a').removeClass('bold');` and in CSS `.bold { font-weight: bold; }`

Comment: what do you mean by active?

Comment: this can be achieved with css.... a{font-weight: 100;} a:active{font-weight:800;}

Comment: @Mat But then if you click anywhere else on the page the bold is removed as well. The idea here is to set the state of the element, which cannot be done (though it can be faked using `:target`) using CSS alone.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest toggling a class instead.

Basically, it removes the class `active` from all the sibling elements, then uses the `.end()` method to select the initial element and add the class `active`:

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">link A</a>
<a href="#">link B</a>
<a href="#">link C</a>
<a href="#">link D</a>
```

Comment: Use `$(this).addClass('active').siblings('a').removeClass('active');`, this way you don't need `end()` and you're targeting only anchors, as other HTML structure is not shown in OP.

Comment: @Tushar Personally, I find it more readable using `.end()`, so I don't intend on changing it since it does the exact same thing. The OP can change the selectors, this is just pseudo-code anyways.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `.not();`  and you can toggle class by using `ToggleClass();` instead of `addClass();`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $('a').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.active{
  font-weight : bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">link A</a>
<a href="#">link B</a>
<a href="#">link C</a>
<a href="#">link D</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Josh Crozier's answer is the best solution for this and should be recommended. But just wanted to share, if anyone still want to do it without using a class, it is not impossible to do :

```
$("a").click(function() {
   $(this).siblings().css("font-weight","normal").end().css("font-weight","bold");
});
```